# Integrate VolumeMeter

Tags: c#, naudio

I have to set the Amplitude of My WAV File. I am using NAudio for this. It's VolumeMeter class has the Amplitude Property.

I am facing a problem integrating this Class with my Audio, as in how do i make it change the Amplitude of my Audio.

My code is:

```
    private void setAmplitude(int val)
    {
        WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader("D:\\us1.wav");
        VolumeMeter meter = new VolumeMeter();

        //set the amplitutde of "reader" to "val"
        //dunno what to type here so that I can link my meter and reader
        //my intention is to use : meter.Amplitude=val;

        WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.Init(reader);
        waveOut.Play();
    }
```

Comment: how do i set the amplitude with meteringsampleprovider class?

Comment: How do i set the volume for a specific amplitude. 
Suppose i want amplitude value 'x' , what should be my volume?

Comment: Any Formula for that @HansPassant?

Comment: have a look at the source code for the NAudioDemo application, which shows how to use the VolumeMeter class.

Comment: How will that help me solve the Amplitude problem @MarkHeath?

Comment: Well the volume meter is for displaying the amplitude of your audio. It has nothing to do with changing the amplitude. Which did you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to change the amplitude of my audio..changing the volume changes the amplitude..louder volume = larger amplitude.
But how loud or soft should the volume be for a specific amplitude?
Is there any relation numerically?
Actually, i want to change the amplitude so that i can change the snr of my audio..
So if there is a direct way of changing the snr then it will be much appreciated...

Comment: then you don't need `VolumeMeter` at all. NAudio has many ways of changing the volume. VolumeWaveProvider16 would probably be easiest for you, or just setting Volume on WaveOut. 1.0 means full volume, values greater will amplify and smaller will attenuate.

Comment: I will go with VolumeWaveProvider16..that's fine..
I want to know if suppose in your example, i set 1.3 as my volume then how much will be the amplitude of my wav file?
Is there a way by which i directly set my amplitude to a specific value without directly changing the volume at all?

Comment: As an addition, changing the volume does not change the SNR.

Comment: Changing the volume changes the Amplitude of the audio leading to change in the SNR..AFAIK